# Auto Tab loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have four input fields(with id):

number1, number2, number3, number4.

I want to have a function that will be called after the validator() .
The function will autotab ie. move the focus into next fields.

I tried the following:

```
  if($('#number').is(':focus')) {
        $("#number2").focus();
    }
    else if($('#number2').is(':focus')) {
        $("#cardnumber3").focus();
    }

    else if($('#number3').is(':focus')) {
        $("#cardnumber4").focus();
    }
```

But the function seems to be running for more than one if function. So my focus moves from one to two to three at a single time.

How can I implement this if function to run only one condition at one time? Or is there a better approach to focus the next input field.

Added HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cardn" id="number" name="number" maxlength= "4">
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see some sample html?

Answer (score 0):

Add a call back function to focus the next one on the valudator() instead of focus to the next  one. The code looks like it's doing just continuosly goes from number1 to number 4.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your html I would write it sort of like this, but your original code should work - only thing I can think of is you're calling it more than once:

```
var $focused = $(":focus");
if($focused.is("#number")) {
    $("#number2").focus();
}
else if($focused.is("#number2")) {
    $("#cardnumber3").focus();
}
else if($focused.is("#number3")) {
    $("#cardnumber4").focus();
}
```